# How to replace a value in a binary file in R?

Tags: r, binaryfiles, seek

I have to work with a (custom) binary file format. The data are too big for my RAM and I just need to import a small part of them, do some calculations and overwrite/replace this part with the new values (so I don't want to import everything, change specific part and write everything back).

I tried a combination of `seek` and `writeBin` but this generates a small file with my new value prepended by zeros:

```r
fn <- tempfile()

writeBin(1L:3L, fn, size = 1L)
readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1] 1 2 3

fh <- file(fn, "wb")
isSeekable(fh)
#> [1] TRUE
seek(fh, 1L, origin = "start", rw = "write")
#> [1] 0
# swap the sign of the second value
writeBin(-2L, fh, size = 1L)
close(fh)

readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1]  0 -2

unlink(fn)
```

---

Using the `ab` mode for appending to the file doesn't help either:

```r
fn <- tempfile()

writeBin(1L:3L, fn, size = 1L)
readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1] 1 2 3

fh <- file(fn, "ab")
isSeekable(fh)
#> [1] TRUE
seek(fh, 1L, origin = "start", rw = "write")
#> [1] 3
# swap the sign of the second value
writeBin(-2L, fh, size = 1L)
close(fh)

readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1] 1 2 3

unlink(fn)
```

My expected output would be `1 -2 3`.

Is there a way to do this in `R` or do I have to use `C` for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found the solution myself: using the mode `"r+b"` supports the replacement of data.

```r
fn <- tempfile()

writeBin(1L:3L, fn, size = 1L)
readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1] 1 2 3

fh <- file(fn, "r+b")
isSeekable(fh)
#> [1] TRUE
seek(fh, 1L, origin = "start", rw = "write")
#> [1] 0
# swap the sign of the second value
writeBin(-2L, fh, size = 1L)
close(fh)

readBin(fn, what = "integer", size = 1L, n = 3L)
#> [1]  1 -2  3

unlink(fn)
```

I didn't tried this one before because the documentation of the *Modes* in `?file` doesn't offer this information:

> ‘"wb"’ Open for writing in binary mode.
>
> ‘"ab"’ Open for appending in binary mode.
>
> ‘"r+"’, ‘"r+b"’ Open for reading and writing.